# How to identify type of error from error object

Tags: swift, exception, enums

The .failed(let e) condition  from the result returns with list of custom exceptions under SDKError enum. On the UI side i have to implement the logic for different types of failures. How it is possible to identify the type of error from the object?

> case .failed(let e as! SDKError):
>
> case .failed(let e):
>                   e.localizedDescription

```
 // UI side implementation
 SDK.getInstance.fetchItems() { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let item):
        self.item = item
    case .failed(let e):
        print("Error=\(e)")
    }
 }

// SDK part
// Type of response from the closure
public enum ResultModel<T, E> {
    case success(T)
    case failed(E)

    var isSuccess: Bool {
       if case .success(_) = self {
           return true
       }
       return false
    }

    var isFailed: Bool {
       if case .failed(_) = self {
           return true
       }
       return false
    }
}

// SDK part
// Enum class for different exceptions
public enum SDKError: Error {
    case UnacceptableStatusCode(Int)
    case UnexpectedResponse(Any)
    case InvalidAuthCredentials(Any)
    case InvalidData(Any)
    case MandatoryPasswordReset(Any)
    case NullDataFound(Any)
    case NullResponse(Any)
}
```

Comment: try  `switch e { case let SDKError.UnacceptableStatusCode(code):`

Comment: Tried,But getting error since the result is of above type  'ResultModel<Item, SDKError>'

`Enum case 'unacceptableStatusCode' is not a member of type 'ResultModel<Item, SDKError>'`

Comment: what type is your `e` var? what `print("Error=\(e)")` prints?

Comment: Error=InvalidData(CodingKeys(stringValue: "item1", intValue: nil))

this is a type error created by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the error type-dispatching `switch` inside another `switch` which distinguishes success from error state:

```
switch result {
case let .failed(error):
  switch error {
  case let SDKError.UnacceptableStatusCode(code): // ...
  // other cases go here
  }
case let .success(value):
  // success handling goes here
}
```